# subject after "than"

Tags: phrases

> The road slopes down through the foothills on the south side of the
>   Lubéron before joining up with the amateur Grand Prix that takes place
>   every day on the RN7, the Nationale Sept that has eliminated more
>   motorists over the years than **is comfortable** to think about as one
>   waits for a gap in the traffic.

( A Year In Provence - Mayle Peter)

What is the subject of "**is comfortable**"?

Thank you.

Comment: Please wait a day or two before choosing an answer. You may get a much better one later! (Also if an answer is not worth upvoting it definitely isn't worth selecting as *the* answer) :-)

Comment: I beg to differ. I hold the badge for quantity of chosen-but-not-upvoted answers.  Answers that satisfy the askers' needs are not always the ones that impress the "experts" here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"one".

One is comfortable to think about...

It's a forward reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's an impersonal sentence.

The Nationale Sept, which is the subject of the previous sentence, has eliminated more drivers than (it) is comfortable to think about. The writer feels uncomfortable thinking about how many drivers were eliminated by the Nationale Sept; "is comfortable" does not, therefore, have a subject.